# Mysql group by 15min does not match total sum

Tags: mysql, sum

I have the following 2 query's but they return a different result. For example if I request the total amount from one terminal I get: 456.

If I then ask it in intervals of 15min, count all the value's up I get 474... How is this possible?

My query to fetch the total amount is the following

```
SELECT   SUM(logs.amount) * ei_relationships.itemprice as income
  ,      currency
FROM     ei_relationships
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN logs ON ei_relationships.id = logs.ei_relationship_id 
WHERE    ei_relationships.event_id = 1
     AND logs.serial = '5B:13:52:28:71:21:ED:F1'
ORDER BY currency, log_time ASC
```

This is my query to get the same data but now divide it in 15min

```
SELECT   SUM(logs.amount) * ei_relationships.itemprice as income
  ,      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(log_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(log_time)%(900) as hour
  ,      currency
FROM     ei_relationships
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN logs ON ei_relationships.id = logs.ei_relationship_id
WHERE    ei_relationships.event_id = 1
     AND logs.serial = '5B:13:52:28:71:21:ED:F1'
GROUP BY hour
ORDER BY currency, log_time ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

As [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html) says:

> If you use a group function in a statement containing no `GROUP BY` clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.

It [also](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) says:

> MySQL extends the use of `GROUP BY` so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the `GROUP BY` clause. This means that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the `GROUP BY` are the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.

Therefore, in both queries, the sum of the `amount` column is multiplied by one of the values from the `itemprice` column; which of those values MySQL will use is indeterminate and therefore, unless every record has the same `itemprice`, the resulting `income` is also indeterminate.

Perhaps you had intended to `GROUP BY currency` and select `SUM(logs.amount * ei_relationships.itemprice) AS income`?